# How to solve following error?

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, menu, whatsapp

I am android developer and develop an android application in which i need whatsapp type menu animation.

I am using lot's off example.

Recenty I used "https://github.com/Tarekajaj/WhatsappMenuReplicate" example.

This original project in android-studio and i am trying to import in eclipse.

But I got the following error.

So can you tell me how to solve this error ?[image]

Thanks

Comment: Firstly uninstall eclipse and download new Android Studio. AS is much better ;) Please paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add API 23 from SDK Manager. Then its works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the fact that `ViewAnimationUtils` class is only   available in API 21 and above.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.html
Are you testing your app on Lollipop? It will not work on older API levels. To use it you need to set min SDK to 21.